# Using shortcode in template file

Tags: templates, shortcode

this is shortcode in template:

```
function shortcode_frame_left( $atts, $content = null)
{

   return '<span class="frame alignleft">'. do_shortcode($content) . '</span>';
}
add_shortcode('frame_left', 'shortcode_frame_left');
```

this is how using in post content:

```
[frame_left] <a href="YOUR-URL"><img src="YOUR-URL" /></a> [/frame_left]
```

I am trying to use this shortcode in template file for displaying post thumbnails. What i try:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {

apply_filters( 'the_content', "[frame_left]".the_post_thumbnail()."[/frame_left]"); 
}
```

and

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {

$thumbnail = '[frame_left]'. the_post_thumbnail() . '[/frame_left]';
echo do_shortcode("$thumbnail");

}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Your shortcode definition is `frame_left`, code examples use `frame_right`. Can I assume you have `frame_right` shortcode defined in same way?

Comment: OH so sorry, that was example, i copy wrong shortcode seems, template have both frame_left and frame_right btw.

Comment: @Ünsal: You don't have to edit your question to include the answer, that will confuse future readers. Just leave it as it was, so people with a similar problem can find the question and the given answer(s). I recommend you edit it and the rollback to the previous revision.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail) echos the thumbnail and returns nothing. You probably want to use [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) which returns it as a string. Your code currently is equivalent to this:

```
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    // Echo the thumbnail
    the_post_thumbnail();
    // Apply the filter but do nothing with the result.
    apply_filters( 'the_content', "[frame_left]"."[/frame_left]");
}

if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    // Echo the thumbnail
    the_post_thumbnail();
    $thumbnail = '[frame_left]' . '[/frame_left]';
    // Echo the <span> with an empty content
    echo do_shortcode("$thumbnail");
}
```

Comment: not working.. for example your 2nd codes result is: <img src=""><span class="frame alignleft"></span>[/frame_left]

Comment: image is displaying but not inside of <span> and there is [/frame_left] which is weird

Comment: oh i got it.. you mean answer is if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    // Echo the thumbnail
    $thumbnail = '[frame_right]' . get_the_post_thumbnail() . '[/frame_right]';
    // Echo the <span> with an empty content
    echo do_shortcode("$thumbnail");
}

Comment: @Ünsal: Indeed, my example is not what you should do, but what your current code is doing. You should just use your current code, but replace `the_post_thumbnail()` with `get_the_post_thumbnail()` (and probably `echo` that `apply_filters()` result?).